# SharePoint: Top Navigation Bar drop down in alphabetical order

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have the following code to display the sub sites in the top global navigation as a multi-level drop down menu:

```
<div id="s4-topheader2" class="s4-pr s4-notdlg">
       <a name="startNavigation"></a>
       <div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
             <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"/>
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          <span class="s4-help">
          <span style="height: 17px; width: 17px; ; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden;" class="s4-clust">
          <a href="#" style="height: 17px; width: 17px; display: inline-block;" onclick="TopHelpButtonClick('HelpHome');return false" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>" id="TopHelpLink" title="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png" alt="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" style="left: -0px !important; top: -309px !important; ;" align="absmiddle" border="0" runat="server" /></a></span>
          </span>
       </div>
       <div class="s4-rp s4-app"></div>
       <div class="s4-lp s4-toplinks">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
             <h2 class="ms-hidden">
                <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,topnav_pagetitle%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
             </h2>
             <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:AspMenu
                   ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
                   Runat="server"
                   EnableViewState="false"
                   DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                   AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                   UseSimpleRendering="true"
                   UseSeparateCss="false"
                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                   StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                   MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="11"
                   SkipLinkText=""
                   CssClass="s4-tn"/>
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
                   <Template_Controls>
                      <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                         ShowStartingNode="False"
                         SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                         id="topSiteMap"
                         runat="server"
                         StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
                   </Template_Controls>
                </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
             </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>
    </div>
```

It works fine, except the sub sites are not in alphabetical order.

I've noticed something interesting; the sites that are not in order are ones that I had moved around. These appear at the end. I tried moving all the subsites to a temporary newly created site and move them back in alphabetical order, but didn't work. It's as if the preserve the order from the site where it was originally created.

I am on SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Comment: Have you asked this question over at sharepoint.stackexchange.com?